# JS self-executing closure: what happens when IIFEs inside have conflicting declarations?

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

I was going through [JavaScript allonge#six](https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read#) and came to this example (short comments after each line of code):

```
((PI) => {             //1 - Outer - PI = 3.14 
   ((PI) => {})(100);   // 2 - IIFE (LOCAL)  PI = 100


  // ((PI) => PI)(100) // alternative1 = LOCAL PI = 100
 //  ((PI) => {return PI;})(100) // alternative2 - LOCAL PI = 100

  return (diameter) => diameter * PI;  // 3 - PI = 3.14
})(3.14)(2)
```

In all of these cases, the argument bounded for PI in the outer function is passed directly to the return statement, thus ignoring the IIFE. The only way one could shadow the "PI" argument is to change the return statement to this:

```
((PI) => (diameter) => diameter * PI)(100)
```

So first Q: Is there another way to shadow the PI argument (the one bound on the outer function) aside from a closure in this case?

Additionally, I ran the code through google developer console line by line and got to a point in the code where the PI value inside the IIFE gets "overwritten" to 3.14 despite being previously bounded to 100. [image: PI inside the IIFE gets overwritten to 3.14 DESPITE BEING BOUNDED TO 100 previously]

Second Q:

What happens to the IIFE inside after it executes, at what point does it get its PI value overwritten to 3.14?

Comment: With ES6 you have `let` which allows you to declare a variable for only the current scope, so you can have, say a variable called `x` outside a for loop and a different variable called `x` inside the for loop without the two overlapping.

Comment: What conflict? Which IIFEs? What do you want to overwrite? What do you want to shadow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it difficult to figure out what exactly you were asking. So I just reorganised the code and added my own comments to try to make things clearer for myself, and hopefully answer some part of your questions.

```
var a = (function a(PI) {
   // In this scope, PI = 3.14

   (function b(PI) {
     // PI = 100
   })(100);

  return function c(diameter) {
    // PI = 3.14, still in scope `a`
    // diameter = 2, passed in from second call
    return diameter * PI;
  };
});

a_result = a(3.14); // == c, with PI = 3.14
c_result = a_result(2); // c called with diameter = 2, PI = 3.14 from scope `a`
```

Feel free to ask more questions about this, using the names and references so I'm on the same page.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't too clear in my initial question; one question was what would happen to function b in this case? as it's self-executing, shouldn't it return 100 to the scope of a and thus shadow whatever you pass into a_result? And the other one was about whether one could manage to shadow the parameter passed to a (the line with a_result) aside from using a closure

Comment: No, b does nothing whatsoever. _Within_ b, PI = 100. It's got a scope all of its own. A scope is accessible to all scopes nested inside it, but those nested scopes can "shadow" the parent scope's variables by making their own. So the `PI` variable in `b` is actually a completely new variable only accessibly from with `b`'s scope.

Comment: If you added a `var PI = 1;` to `c`, then `c` wouldn't be able to see `a`'s scoped `PI` variable. It would only see its own because it has "shadowed" that variable name.

Comment: (I will incorporate all this into the answer as soon as all your questions are answered, by the way.)

Comment: Ooh, I get it, I thought function b - being an IIFE would lead to the creation of a variable that takes the name of the parameter (PI in this case) but you're right it doesn't do anything (even if you'd add a return value). But then what happens to it? And then there's the issue with the image I added: in this case within `b` you'd have a value of 3.14 for PI, despite it already executing with a bounded value. But thanks so much, that cleared part of the question very well

Comment: Nothing happens as a result of `b`, because `b` did nothing. That PI = 3.14 in the image is just misleading. It's probably getting confused with the PI in the IIFE and the scope outside it. If you `console.log` from within `b`, it would log `100`.